# Scope in Python 3.6.And the Error

Tags: python, scope

How does the code below give the output as None?

```
def funct(x):
    x=7

x=11
x=test(x)
print(x)
```

Here is another code snippet:-

```
def func():
    print (x)
    x = 90

x = 1
func()
```

The output for this should be 90!  The scope is searched as Local ,Enclosed , Global ,Build-in .Either x should here be searched as local or global
Please explain.

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` here is *not* a global variable in the scope of the functions, as functions naturally create their own namespaces, which do not include any outer variables not passed in as a parameter.

There are many issues with your code, including the order of function calling, and the order of the operations inside the functions; but to answer your question in the broadest way possible, in order for you to access the `x` variable defined outside of your functions, in a greater scope that is, you need to reference its namespace, by prepending `global x` inside the body of each of your functions.

Read up on [Python variables and scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html), and recheck the other errors in your code I have stated above.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet returns **None** for the simple fact that you didn't return *any* value from the function.  You defined **x** as a local parameter, not a global variable.  Since you didn't return any value, your call **test(x)** (which does not match the function name of **funct**), will become a value of **None**.  This is clearly defined in the Python documentation.  To get the local value back to your main program, try this:

```
test(x):
    x = 7
    return x

x = 11
x = test(x)
print(x)
```

Also, please note that your initial value of 11 is entirely ignored in the main program, and that your function ignores the value it's given.  You should shorten this example to

```
func():
    return 7

print(func())
```

---

Your second example will print the external value of **1** because you have *not* defined a local variable **x** at that point, and a function is allowed to *reference* global variables.

However, when you *assign* a value in the next, you create a local variable -- you have not declared **x** to be global, so you can't assign to the **x** in the main program.

Again, you do not return any value.  Therefore, back in the main program, **func()** evaluates to **None**.

Does that clear up what happened?